# Linux/Solaris verification ( after hostname change ) in files according to hostname rule

Tags: linux, solaris, perl, shell-scripting

According to the following Perl command

( this command part of ksh script )

I can replaced  old hostnames with new hostnames in Linux or Solaris

```
 previos_machine_name=linux1a
 new_machine_name=Red_Hat_linux1a

 export previos_machine_name
 export new_machine_name
```

.

```
      perl -i -pe 'next if /^ *#/; s/(\b|[[:^alnum:]])$ENV{previos_machine_name}(\b|[[:^alnum:]])/$1$ENV{new_machine_name}$2/g'  file
```

EXPLAIN:  according to perl command - we **not** replace hostnames on the follwoing case:

**RULE:** [NUMBERS]||[letter]HOSTNAME[NUMBERS]||[letter]

my question

after I used the Perl command in order to replace all old hostnames with new hostnames
based on the "RULE" in the Perl command

how to verify that the old hostnames not exist in file ?

for example

```
   previos_machine_name=linux1a

   new_machine_name=Red_Hat_linux1a

   more file

   AAARed_Hat_linux1a          verification should be ignore from this line
   @Red_Hat_linux1a$             verification should be match this line
   P=Red_Hat_linux1a            verification should be match this line
   XXXRed_Hat_linux1aZZZ         verification should be ignore from this line
   .
   .
   .
   .
```

Comment: Are we talking a few (less than 10) machines or a lot here?

Comment: why its important ? , any way is could be 1 machine or more then 20 machines depend file configuration , and in my script each time I verify one hostname !

Comment: Well, if it is only a few machine, maybe just do it by hand or commandline "grep".

Comment: but I need to check more 100 files , and I need to match exactly to the RULE: [NUMBERS]||[letter]HOSTNAME[NUMBERS]||[letter]

Comment: Understand. If possible, post the script. Then someone maybe able to modify it for you. Or if it is a stand script come with distribution, post the path so we can look it up in our machine.

Comment: script isn't the issue , the issue is to verify not existing of  the old hostname according to RULE - [NUMBERS]||[letter]HOSTNAME[NUMBERS]||[letter]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use fowlling line to print matching string

```
perl -i -pe 'next if /^ *#/; if ($_ =~ /(\b|[[:^alnum:]])$ENV{previos_machine_name}(\b|[[:^alnum:]])/) { print STDOUT $_; }'  file
```

If it print out empty, that means no old hostname exist.